# pass array from one blade template to another - laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

How can a variable created in one template passed to another one. I have a list of countries created in blade.php file and since it would be used multiple times in different views, it makes more sense to just include the file when needed instead of just listing the countries all over again.
countries.blade.php

```
$countriesarray('' => Lang::get('candidate/cv_builder.Select Country'),
                 'United States' => Lang::get('candidate/cv_builder.United States'),
                 'United Kingdom' => Lang::get('candidate/cv_builder.United Kingdom'),
```

personal.blade.php

```
{{Form::select('nationality', @include('profiles.countries', array('countries'=>$received)) , Auth::user()->nationality)}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `share` in your controller (not in Blade):

```
View::share('countries', $countriesarray);
```

and you will have defined `$countries` variable in all your templates